# Replacing in Vim every fourth occurrence

Tags: vim

I have a file like this:

```
Question 1
b) answer b
c) answer c
a) answer a
d) answer d

Question 2
a) answer a
d) answer d
b) answer b
c) answer c
```

Alls answers are unsorted. I need to set all the first answers (no matter what letter, just that they are the first answer) to `v)` and the rest to `x)`, so the output will be:

```
Question 1
v) answer b
x) answer c
x) answer a
x) answer d

Question 2
v) answer a
x) answer d
x) answer b
x) answer c
```

Is it possible with one-line command?

Comment: If the questions are always on one line and there are always exactly 4 answers, you can probably do this with a macro that you repeat for each question. Otherwise this seems difficult in Vim and I would probably reach for Perl or Python instead.

Comment: What do you mean by "every fourth occurrence?"

Comment: @DavidYoung My original approach was replacing the `[a-d]) ` occurrences in a position multiple of 4 (1, 4, 8,...) to `v) `, and then replace the rest to `x) `. Maybe I was overthinking it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
:%s/\d\+\_s\zs\l\ze)/v/ | %s/\D\_s\zs\l\ze)/x/
```

But this is only for your special case.

Little bit of explanation:

- `%s`  substitute in all lines
- `\d\+` one or more numbers
- `\_s` white space or end-of-line
- `\zs` and `\ze` start and end of the match
- `\l` lowercase character: `[a-z]`
- `\D` non-digit: `[^0-9]`
- `|` can be used to separate commands, so you can give multiple commands in one line.

Comment: This will only work if the file literally contains the text `Question 1\n` ... `Question 2\n` and so on. Usually in questions like this, the text in the sample is just placeholders for the actual question text, the actual answer text... this is just a note for the OP so they understand that this will only work with the literal text provided in the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you really wanted a one line sure. Anything can be made into a one liner if you use enough `|` to chain commands together.

You can do the iteration your self and run a different substitution command depending on how many of the pattern you have seen.

```
:let i = 0 | g/^[abcd])/if i % 4 == 0 | s//v)/ | else | s//x)/ | endif | let i = i + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If all the questions have the same number of lines, you could do this.

Starting with the cursor on the first column of the first line (in normal mode), you could record a macro (here, into `a`) that will do this for one block:

```
qajrvj^V}0rx'>)q
```

In more detail:

1. `qa`    record a macro in register a
2. `jrv`   move down one line and replace the first character with v
3. `j^V}`  (type ^V as Ctrl-V) visually block select the first characters of the rest of the lines of the block
4. `0`     make sure we are on column 0 (this is important if we run into the end of the file)
5. `rx`    replace these characters with x
6. `'>`    go to the end of the last visual selection
7. `)`     go to the next sentence (the beginning of the next question)
8. `q`     stop recording the macro

This assumes all questions are on one line (this would be easy to change), that we are at the first column of the question line when the macro is run (also a pretty small change to generalize this) and that all answers are one line (the approach would need to be changed a bit, but generalizing this wouldn't be too much harder).

Now you can run this again with `@a` (and after that, `@@` repeats the last run macro). If you want to turn this into a recursive macro (which will keep running until one of the actions, probably a motion, fails), you can use this to append the recursive call to the end of the macro:

```
qA@aq
```

Using a capital register name means append to that register, rather than overwrite it. If you do this, and all the questions follow the restrictions, you can apply this replacement to an entire file by running the macro only once (manually).

You could also turn this into a function using the `:normal` command, if you wanted to keep it around for later use. If you do this, I would suggest spreading it out over several `:normal` commands and commenting it similar to how I did above.